# In Express.js how would I write a route/regex to capture all US states?

Tags: regex, node.js, express

At the moment I have the states in a string as follows:

```
var states = 'AL|AK|AR|AZ|CA|CO|CT|DC|DE|FL|GA|HI|IA|ID|IL...';
```

I would like to capture

> mydomain.com/CA/more-stuff

Into two separate parameters.  The first one with the state information, the second one with the additional.  I know how to get the additional information:

```
app.get('/' ??? + '/:additional', ...);
```

How can I capture the state information?

Comment: Why not to use "/:state/:additional" and then validate the state internally that would allow you to return a nice error object for invalid input?

Answer (score 2):

If you define it as a parameter in the path...

```
app.get('/:stateabbr/:additional', ...);
```

You can validate it with [`app.param()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.param):

```
app.param('stateabbr', function (req, res, next, abbr) {
    var stateAbbrs = /AL|AK|AR|AZ|CA|CO|CT|DC|DE|FL|GA|HI|IA|ID|IL|../i

    if (stateAbbrs.test(abbr)) {
        next()
    } else {
        next(new Error('Unrecognized State abbreviation.'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
var states = 'AL|AK|AR|AZ|CA|CO|CT|DC|DE|FL|GA|HI|IA|ID|IL...';
app.get('/:state('+ states + ')/:additional', function(req,res,next){
    res.send('state:'+req.params.state+',additional:'+req.params.additional);
})
```

I've tested it and it should work as You requested :)